# Python read file by line and write into a different file

Tags: python

SO basically what I am trying to do is that I am trying to make it so I can read a file line by line, and then have a certain text added after the text displayed

For Ex.

## Code:

```
file = open("testlist.txt",'w')
file2 = open("testerlist.txt",'r+')

//This gives me a syntax error obviously.

file.write1("" + file + "" + file2 + "")
```

## Textlist

In my testlist.txt it lists as:

> os

## Testerlist

In my testerlist.txt it lists as:

> 010101

I am trying to copy one text from one file and read another file and add it to the beginning of a new file for ex.[accounts.txt].

## My End Result

For my end result I am trying to have it be like:

> os010101

(btw I have all the correct code, its just that I am using this as an example so if I am missing any values its just because I was to lazy to add it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `file.read()` to read the contents of a file. Then just concatenate the data from two files and write to the output file:

```
with open("testlist.txt") as f1, open("testerlist.txt") as f2, \
        open("accounts.txt", "w") as f3:
    f3.write(f1.read().strip() + f2.read().strip())
```

Note that 'mode' is not required when opening files for reading.

If you need to write the lines in particular order, you could use `file.readlines()` to read the lines into a list and `file.writelines()` to write multiple lines to the output file, e.g.:

```
 with open("testlist.txt") as f1, open("testerlist.txt") as f2, \
            open("accounts.txt", "w") as f3:
        f1_lines = f1.readlines()
        f3.write(f1_lines[0].strip())
        f3.write(f2.read().strip())
        f3.writelines(f1_lines[1:])
```

Comment: dam, see like yeah, that code does work and does what its expose to do but the thing is, it spaces the text file when it writes it, such as if I have test in testlist.txt and if i also have test in testerlist.txt it writes in accounts.txt test test with then being spaced im trying to get that test test not spaced so it turns out like this: testtest

Comment: Then just use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! If you wouldn't mind, and I know this might be a little much but, could you help me with making the testlist.txt read line by line and make it so when it reads the first line it writes that first line and plus the entire testlist.txt for ex. [in testlist.txt it would say aa ab ac ad ae....  zz and so on. I already have the list dont worry] [And in testerlist.txt it would have 010101, 010201, 01,03,01 and so on] I want the first line to write the, first line text + the entire testerlist.txt and then once its done reading it moves to the 2nd line and so on.

Comment: Thank you, so what I was thinking of was like, I will have one word (or multiple) in a textfile and from the text file it would write the word that is in the textfile and then it would write all the lines in testlist.txt for ex[ in testlist.txt = test] [and inside my testerlist.txt would be numbers such as, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, helpmeh, 7] and what I want to do is take that one word and write it multiple times so like if I ran the python script it would write: test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, testhelpmeh.

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like this:

```
with open('testlist.txt', 'r') as f:
    input1 = f.read()

with open('testerlist.txt', 'r') as f:
    input2 = f.read()

output = input1+input2
with open("accounts.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(output)
```

Comment: That code works but is there anyways I can have it write code and not have input1 and input2 on different lines in the text file, more specifically have it read both files and combine them into one source of text